# Wagtail TypeError: 'parent' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: wagtail

I got following error and the problem is that I do not know what causes this error, I can not add that whole code. I use method described here [Inline Panels and Model Clusters](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/reference/pages/panels.html#inline-panels-and-model-clusters) If it is possible to find out what exactly leads to this error, tell me please, and I'll post the code.

Just in case, here is a link to the model. [gist](https://gist.github.com/khashashin/5f9442d3ec655a8e8e9757b86538111d)

And here is my wagtail_hooks.py. [gist2](https://gist.github.com/khashashin/2f9447a995afeba11ed219e671f84bff)

```
$ py manage.py check
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\xakep\GitHub\treichle_cup\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\xakep\GitHub\treichle_cup\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\xakep\GitHub\treichle_cup\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\xakep\GitHub\treichle_cup\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\xakep\GitHub\treichle_cup\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\check.py", line 68, in handle
    fail_level=getattr(checks, options['fail_level']),
  File "C:\Users\xakep\GitHub\treichle_cup\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\xakep\GitHub\treichle_cup\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xakep\GitHub\treichle_cup\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\xakep\GitHub\treichle_cup\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\xakep\GitHub\treichle_cup\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\xakep\GitHub\treichle_cup\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 254, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\xakep\GitHub\treichle_cup\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\xakep\GitHub\treichle_cup\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\xakep\GitHub\treichle_cup\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\xakep\GitHub\treichle_cup\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\xakep\GitHub\treichle_cup\env\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\xakep\GitHub\treichle_cup\treichle_cup\urls.py", line 7, in <module>
    from wagtail.wagtailadmin import urls as wagtailadmin_urls
  File "C:\Users\xakep\GitHub\treichle_cup\env\lib\site-packages\wagtail\wagtailadmin\urls\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from wagtail.wagtailadmin.api import urls as api_urls
  File "C:\Users\xakep\GitHub\treichle_cup\env\lib\site-packages\wagtail\wagtailadmin\api\urls.py", line 13, in <module>
    for fn in hooks.get_hooks('construct_admin_api'):
  File "C:\Users\xakep\GitHub\treichle_cup\env\lib\site-packages\wagtail\wagtailcore\hooks.py", line 49, in get_hooks
    search_for_hooks()
  File "C:\Users\xakep\GitHub\treichle_cup\env\lib\site-packages\wagtail\wagtailcore\hooks.py", line 43, in search_for_hooks
    list(get_app_submodules('wagtail_hooks'))
  File "C:\Users\xakep\GitHub\treichle_cup\env\lib\site-packages\wagtail\utils\apps.py", line 25, in get_app_submodules
    yield name, import_module('%s.%s' % (name, submodule_name))
  File "C:\Users\xakep\GitHub\treichle_cup\env\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\xakep\GitHub\treichle_cup\team_rooster\wagtail_hooks.py", line 47, in <module>
    modeladmin_register(TournamentModelAdmin)
  File "C:\Users\xakep\GitHub\treichle_cup\env\lib\site-packages\wagtail\contrib\modeladmin\options.py", line 594, in modeladmin_register
    instance = modeladmin_class()
  File "C:\Users\xakep\GitHub\treichle_cup\env\lib\site-packages\wagtail\contrib\modeladmin\options.py", line 522, in __init__
    self.modeladmin_instances.append(ModelAdminClass(parent=self))
  File "C:\Users\xakep\GitHub\treichle_cup\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 573, in __init__
    raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % list(kwargs)[0])
TypeError: 'parent' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

**UPDATE**

I found out that is related to wagtail_hooks.py I just removed my TournamentModelAdmin class
And if i do check again i didn't get errors.

Comment: It looks like you set your TournamentModelAdmin(ModelAdminGroup) class with items that are just models, not actual ModelAdmin items. I could be missing something but I am pretty sure you cannot just pass in a list of models, they have to actually be ModelAdmin classes (with `model` set inside the class)

Answer (score 3):

As @lb-ben-johnston said my mistake was that I directly added the model. So I just changed my code from that:

```
class TournamentModelAdmin(ModelAdminGroup):
    menu_label = 'Tournament'
    menu_icon = 'folder-open-inverse'
    menu_order = 500
    items = (GoupstageTournamentModel,
        FinalphaseTournamentModel, TournamentPage)

modeladmin_register(TournamentModelAdmin)
```

To:

```
class TournamentModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = TournamentPage
    menu_label = 'Tournament'
    menu_icon = 'fa-trophy'
    list_display = ('starts_at', 'ends_at')
    list_per_page = 5
    search_fields = ('title', 'starts_at')

class GroupstageModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = GroupstageTournamentModel
    menu_label = 'Gruppenphase'
    menu_icon = 'fa-user-times'
    list_display = ('number', 'starts_at',
        'team_1_dress', 'team_1', 'team_1_total_score', 'team_1_total_points',
        'team_2_total_points', 'team_2_total_score', 'team_2', 'team_2_dress')
    list_per_page = 10
    list_filter = ('number', 'starts_at')
    search_fields = ('number', 'starts_at')

class FinalstageModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = FinalphaseTournamentModel
    menu_label = 'Finalphase'
    menu_icon = 'fa-user-plus'
    search_fields = ('number', 'starts_at')   

class TreichleCupModelAdmin(ModelAdminGroup):
    menu_label = 'Treichle-Cup'
    menu_icon = 'folder-open-inverse'
    menu_order = 200
    items = (
        TournamentModelAdmin,
        GroupstageModelAdmin,
        FinalstageModelAdmin,
    )

modeladmin_register(TreichleCupModelAdmin)
```

And its works well! Thanks @lb-ben-johnston